# How to read the stored messages in mesibo flutter sdk?

Tags: flutter, mesibo

The mesibo documentation says that to read the stored messages you have to create a read session, how do i do that using mesibo sdk for flutter, there doesn't seem to be any "ReadSession" method.

https://docs.mesibo.com/api/messaging/reading-messages/

I tried to create an instance from the profile object but I couldn't find any method for getting the read session.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, you are right, the Readsession is currently available in native APIs only, it will be available in Flutter in the next version planned for Dec 29th.

Comment: Hi, we have updated Flutter SDK with MesiboReadsession functionalities and examples.  Please let us know if you face any issues. https://pub.dev/packages/mesibo_flutter_sdk